# Can a rotation calculated in GN be applied to child objects?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How I imagined it:

- calculate some arbitrary rotation in GN (I am utilizing the Sample Curve functionality, the Tangent vector in particular)
- apply this rotation to an object tree

I can not make this work, and I suppose the reason would be that geometry updates that are done via GN are not "visible" to other objects nor their drivers; probably because the GN updates take place *after* all drivers are evaluated? (The "Copy Rotation" constraint doesn't do the trick for me either, probably for the same reason...)

Comment: I don't know of a way to automatically apply the rotation to all child elements, but by assigning a *Geometry Nodes* modifier to the child elements as well and placing a few nodes there, it's solvable. Are you also interested in such a solution? Another question: Where should the pivot point actually be when rotating the child elements?

Comment: This is kind of the difference between transformation and deformation-- you'd see the same issues with an armature deformed model.  You should probably be looking into the use of vertex groups for constraints, which will allow you to copy deformation.  But specifics depend on your specific GN: does it maintain stable topo?  Does it use instanced meshes?  Worst case scenario, you make three objects to instance specific verts of your GN, you shrinkwrap empties to them, and you damped track + locked track those empties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, with *Geometry Nodes* the transformation of the object remains unchanged, and only the processed geometry within the object changes directly.

Also for this reason you don't have direct access to this rotation with drivers.

But...

You have the possibility to store certain values in the geometry, and to read them in another object also with another *Geometry Nodes* modifier.

For example, in the parent object use the following setup:

[image]

And in all child objects use something like this:

[image]

You can, of course, store the values in any attribute domain, but for the sake of simplicity I have converted the geometry into an instance and stored the values in the attribute domain *Instances*.

In the child objects you then get the data via the node `Object Info` and with the node `Sample Index` you can get the values of the attribute "gnRotation" in this case. Optionally you can also get the position of the parent object and use it as pivot point for a rotation.